# Conditional probability of having intellectual disability

Tags: conditional-probability, medicine, disease

I'm reading this [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31321490/) about a genetic disease. In the paper, there's the following table

[image]

where $DD$ means developmental delay and $ID$ means intellectual disability.

From the table (last column) we know that

$$
P(ID \& DD) = 0.82 \\
P(ID) = 0.43 \\
P(DD) = 0.52 \\
$$

Now, imagine that we have already observed that a patient has $DD$ but we don't know if they have $ID$, which is the probability of this patient having also $ID$? This is, how can we compute $P(ID | DD)$?

I've tried using the definition of the conditional probability

$$
P(ID | DD) = \frac{P(ID, DD)}{P(DD)} = \frac{0.82}{0.52} = 1.58
$$

which doesn't make any sense.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't read the paper, but you must be misinterpreting what the numbers represent. Probability of having both *cannot* be higher than the probability of having either of them. The paper in the abstract says something about "and/or", so most likely this is not "&".

Comment: Yes, you're right, I read it again and it says "Developmental delay and/or intellectual disability were noted in the vast majority of affected individuals (81.7% = 49/60).". So 0.82 is the probability of having DD and/or ID. I'll edit the question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is the notation in the paper (not your formula).  ID/DD in this context means ID *or* DD (not ID *and* DD).  In your formula, $P(ID,DD) = P(ID \cap DD)$, but in the paper ID/DD means $P(ID \cup DD)$.  If there are 49 that have either (or both) and there are 26+31=57 in the individual categories, this means there was an overcount of 8...thus, the number that have both is 8 or 8/60 = 13.3%.  (Note, the clue was that the intersection count can't be larger than either of the individual counts.)

If you replace your numerator with this value, you should get the desired conditional probability.